# SQL Server: remote function calls are not allowed within a function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have below scalar function that calls a stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ServiceContracted] 
    (@Id INT,
     @num VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
   DECLARE @Today DATETIME

   SET @Today = GETDATE()

   DECLARE @resultString varchar(50)

   EXEC @ReturnValue = [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].[MyStoreProcedure] 
             @Id, @num, @Today, @resultString OUTPUT

   RETURN @ReturnValue
END
```

`ReturnValue` can be 1 or 0.

This function is called from the where clause of a select.

In the where clause among other conditions I do:

```
... AND [dbo].[ServiceContracted] > 0
```

When executing the select I get an error:

> Remote function calls are not allowed within a function.

I cannot convert the scalar function into a stored procedure because then I cannot call it from a select.

Comment: What is your question? You cannot execute procedures inside functions as you already have discovered.

Comment: @PeterHenell my question is: is there any work around to do it? I have discovered that it is not possible, but maybe a work around?

Comment: Use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: Can you change `[LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].[MyStoreProcedure]`?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov No, I can't....Are you telling me that changing it to the same server instead of using linkserver will work?

Comment: @user1624552 You can add XML input parameter, pass all Ids and Nums call it (as insert..exec) before running your query then join result table to your query